# SWI-Prolog, writing backwards

Tags: prolog

This is a predicate that is supposed to write backwards out of a list, but since 'tab(-2)' doesn't work I was wondering if there are other predicates, or a different way of using'tab/1' in order to move backwards.
(Using 'reverse/2' is not an option in this case).

Im fairly new to all this, so I hope I did everything right, any kind of help would be appreciated.

```
snakeprint([X|Xs],Counter1,Counter2,Y,2):-
   tab((Y*3)-3),                               
   write(X),                                 
   tab(-2),                                  
   C1 is Counter1-1,
   snakeshift([X|Xs],V),
   snakeprint(V,C1,Counter2,Y,2).
```

Answer (score 0):

```
snakeprint([H|T]) :-
    snakeprint(T),
    write(H).

snakeprint([]).
```

```
Input: ["M", "a", "r", "y", " ", "h", "a", "d"]
Output: dah yraM
```